# compareSync always false

Tags: javascript, express, bcrypt

I am trying to build a login/registration feature on my web app that lets the user to login and register in the database.

In register API there's nothing wrong with that as far as I know because it can add a user to my database.

//register API

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO AUTHENTICATION (name, email, password) \
 VALUES (?, ?, ?)`;
myDB.query(sql, [req.body.name, req.body.email, bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8)],
    (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(500).send("There was a problem registering the user.")
        } else {
            let sql = "SELECT * FROM AUTHENTICATION WHERE email = ?"
            myDB.query(sql, [req.body.email], (error, rows) => {
                if (error) {
                    return res.status(500).send("There was a problem getting user")
                } else {
                    //change rows.email to rows.id to be more secure
                    let token = jwt.sign({ email: rows.id }, config.secret, {
                        expiresIn: 86400
                    });
                    res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token: token, user: rows });
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

Here, I'm having a problem because compareSync always returns false.

//login API

```
let sql = "SELECT * FROM AUTHENTICATION WHERE email = ?";
myDB.query(sql, [req.body.email, req.body.password], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send('Error on the server')
    } else {
        if (!results) {
            return res.status(404).send('No user found.');
        } else {
            //compare password from client side and hash password in database.
            let checkPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, results[0].password);
            console.log(checkPassword);
            if (!checkPassword) {
                //if password doesn't match
                return res.status(401).send({
                    auth: false, token: null
                });
            } else {
                //password matched
                let token = jwt.sign({ id: results.id }, config.secret, {
                    expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
                });
                res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token: token, user: results });
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I think in this part it always return false

```
let checkPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, results[0].password);
            console.log(checkPassword);
```

Comment: Can you try generating hash before making DB query. And then pass it.

Comment: Did you try logging the hash generated during registration and the values of `req.body.password` and `results[0].password` when logging in?

Comment: @Ry- I find your comment helpful because I logged the req.body.password and results[0].password is not the same in length. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think bcrypt.compare can take some time to compare 
so you can try this way

```
let sql = "SELECT * FROM AUTHENTICATION WHERE email = ?";
myDB.query(sql, [req.body.email, req.body.password],async (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send('Error on the server')
    } else {
        if (!results) {
            return res.status(404).send('No user found.');
        } else {
            //compare password from client side and hash password in database.
            let checkPassword =await bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, results[0].password);
            console.log(checkPassword);
            if (checkPassword) {
                   //password matched
                    let token = jwt.sign({ id: results.id }, config.secret, {
                        expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
                    });
                    res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token: token, user: results });
                } else {
                       //if the password doesn't match

                      return res.status(401).send({
                        auth: false, token: null
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: `compare` is asynchronous, yes. `compareSync`, on the other hand, is not.